# Can I still get a list of users Instagram posts using the Instagram API v1? (users/self/media/recent/)

Tags: api, instagram, laravel-5.7

I've just started building a simple import images app for my company. We have a normal image upload and would like to provide the ability to import images from Instagram as well. I have coded the basic functionality in Laravel. Users can authorise with Instagram and then I have a successfully called 'users/self/media/recent/' which is returning the correct data in SandBox mode. I get a list of recent posts, exactly what I want.

But looking at the developer's page, https://www.instagram.com/developer/ the API is being completely depreciated in 2020. And it also states the following:

> Public Content - all remaining capabilities to read public media on a user's behalf on December 11, 2018

In my mind, this reads like calls to 'users/self/media/recent/' should be depeciated already. I'm just worried I put this code/app live next week and its already depreciated outside of sandbox mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, the documentation for this is hard to find. At the bottom of this post its states that:

> After December 11, 2018, the Instagram Platform API will only support
> the instagram_basic permission. This can be utilized to make the API
> calls for the following remaining endpoints:
>
> /users/self - Get information about the owner of the access token
>
> /users/self/media/recent - Get the most recent media published by the owner of the access token
>
> /media/media-id/comments - Get a list of recent comments on your media object. This is only supported for media obtained through the /users/self/media/recent endpoint

https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2018/10/31/instagram-graph-api-hashtag-search-launch/

So I guess that will still work until 2020.